# Graphite: append a "current time" point to the end of a series

Tags: graphite

I have a "succeeded" metric that is just the timestamp. I want to see the time between successive successes (this is how long the data is stale for). I have

```
derivative(Success)
```

but I also want to know how long between the last success time and the current time. since `derivative` transforms `xs[n]` to `xs[n+1] - xs[n]`, the "last" delta doesn't exist. How can I do this? Something like:

```
derivative(append(Success, now()))
```

I don't see any graphite functions for appending series, and I don't see any user-defined graphite functions.

The general problem is to be alerted when the data is stale, via graphite monitoring. There may be a better solution than the one I'm thinking about.

Answer (score 4):

`identity` is a function whose value at any given time is the timestamp of that time.

`keepLastValue` is a function that takes a series and replicates data points forward over gaps in the data.

So then `diffSeries(identity("now"), keepLastValue(Success))` will be a "sawtooth" series that climbs steadily while `Success` isn't updated, and jumps down to zero (or close to it — there might be some time skew) every time `Success` has a data point. If you use graphite monitoring to get the current value of that expression and compare it to some threshold, it will probably do what you want.